# Generate a PDF with XSL/FO from XSLT (html)

Tags: html, xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a XML and a XSLT that generates a HTML output.

I would like to generate a PDF with XSL/FO that gives a render like the HTML output, just paged in PDF.

For this I understood that I had to use a XSL/FO stylesheet, that generates a .fo file, and then that I have to use Apache FOP to generate a pdf from the .fo file.

My question is: how to have the XSL/FO .xsl stylesheet that generates the .fo file, from my XSLT .xsl stylesheet that generates a HTML file ?

Is there any easy way to transform a XSL (html) to the other XSL (xsl/fo) ?

Thank you

Comment: More specifics are likely required. Like does your HTML use css and is that css inline or external. Does it use Javascript to draw dynamically?

Comment: My HTML use CSS (inline) and no javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple people have produced XHTML to FO stylesheets at various times.  See, e.g., 'xhtml2fo.xsl' on the 'XHTML to XSL-FO' tab of https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets/.

Using your inline CSS would require parsing the CSS and transforming the properties into the nearest (often identical) XSL-FO properties.

Comment: The URL now seems to be https://www.antennahouse.com/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML or the HTML as input for the XSL-FO transformation.

You may be able to use your XSL as a starting point for the XSL-FO stylesheet. Replace the HTML output blocks with XSL-FO commands.

As an alternative, you could look into CSS Paged Media. Then you can use your existing HTML, plus a CSS stylesheet that's derived from your existing CSS.